# Windows CMD Line - Syntax Error- Parameter format not correct when trying to run command "del ..\C\D"

Tags: windows, command-line, command-line-arguments

I have 4 folders, with A being the parent, B and C being the child of A, and D being the child of C.

A -> B

A -> C -> D

In folder B I want to generate a build via NPM and then to move the new folder over to D after deleting the previous version.

So to do this I'm trying to run the following script in the command line:

react-scripts build && rd /s/q ../C/D  && move build ../C/D

Upon running this command however, I receive the following error:

Parameter format not correct - "C".

What is causing this error in particular and what would be the proper syntax to run this command?

Answer (score 0):

Windows cmd prompt often requires paths to be in double quotes.

```
C:\Users\Me>mkdir c/d
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
    
C:\Users\Me>mkdir "c/d"
```

Windows powershell will accept the paths without quotes.

```
PS C:\Users\Gordon> mkdir c/d


    Directory: C:\Users\Me\c


Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
d-----         7/20/2022  11:51 AM                d
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example, just swap / (forward slash) with \ (backward slash) and you would probably be good to go...

```
react-scripts build && rd \s\q ..\C\D && move build ..\C\D
```

If your folder or file has empty spaces in the name you'd want to surround it with quotes.